# How to track scroll depth of Facebook Pixel in AMP page using amp-analytics?

Tags: json, amp-html, facebook-pixel, amp-analytics

Any idea how to track `scroll depth` for **Facebook pixel** in AMP Page using `amp-analytics`?

I've tried but still failed to get & show depth parameter, below are my code:

```
 {
    "vars": {
        "pixelId": "123"
    },
    "triggers": {
        
        "scrollPings1": {
            "on": "scroll",
            "request": "event",
            "scrollSpec": {
                "verticalBoundaries": [25]
            },
            "vars": {
                "eventName": "ScrollDepth"

            }
        },

        "scrollPings2": {
            "on": "scroll",
            "request": "event",
            "scrollSpec": {
                "verticalBoundaries": [50]
            },
            "vars": {
                "eventName": "ScrollTracking",
                "content_name": "ScrollDepth"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe this will be helpful
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/analytics-vendors.amp.html#L2028